# Programming Logic

Tags: java, logic

wanted some feedback, m fixing a bug and wanted to ask if there is any problems with my logic below, my if, else-if logic. Whether its correct. M looking at a new codebase and wanted to make sure this logic is correct. The if and else statements I have commented out, but those parts I am not sure. Will these statements both be hit ? Please do let me know, or if any other issues. Thanks

```
 try {
  if (data.length == 0 && _routeOnEmptyBytearray) 
        _receivedBytearrayZero = true;
    }

 else if (data.length >= 0) {
        if (_outStr == null){
            _receivedFileContent = true;
            fileCreate();
        }
        _outStr.write(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is not possible to say that the logic is correct or not because we don't know what you do with that method. But is possible to see that if data is null your code throw a NullPointerException and also if _outstr is null if the code of filCreate doesn't initialize it.

Comment: Without knowing the requirements of this method, how can anyone possibly say whether its logic is correct?  This is like saying "I bought some size 10 shoes; is this the right size for me?" to someone who's never seen my feet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both if and else statement must be have open and close braces 
or do not have

Answer (score 0):

The code above will not compile, because "}" after `_receivedBytearrayZero = true;` closes the try-block and is not followed by `catch`. The `else` statement will not be reached.

Answer (score 0):

Add a brace after the first if condition and add catch after try block as shown below

```
try {
    if (data.length == 0 && _routeOnEmptyBytearray) {
        _receivedBytearrayZero = true;
    } else 
        if (data.length >= 0) {
            if (_outStr == null) {      
                _receivedFileContent = true;
                fileCreate();
            }
            _outStr.write(data);
        }
} catch(Exception e) {
}
```